# Unable connect elasticache using spring-redis unknown host

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have the next issue in my project.

I want to connect my AWS-elasticache, but it's not possible

Here my configuration.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean// to use in my local machine
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "redis", name = "cluster", havingValue = "not")
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(@Value("${redis.host}") String host,
                                                       @Value("${redis.port}") Integer port,
                                                       @Value("${redis.password}") String password) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
        configuration.setPassword(password);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean// configure to elasticaceh
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "redis", name = "cluster", havingValue = "yes", matchIfMissing = true)
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisClusterConnectionFactory(@Value("${redis.host}") String host,
                                                              @Value("${redis.port}") Integer port) {
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        clusterConfiguration.clusterNode(host, port);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfiguration);
}

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("cacheManageMaster")
    public CacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        Duration expiration = Duration.ofHours(24);
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory).cacheDefaults(
                RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                        .disableCachingNullValues()
                        .serializeValuesWith(
                                RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
                                        new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()
                                )
                        ).entryTtl(expiration)
        ).build();
        redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(false);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }
}
```

But I got an exception, here stackTrace

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1602) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1533) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:479) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:105) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:227) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to elastic-cache-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com/<unresolved>:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216) ~[lettuce-core-6.2.3.RELEASE.jar:6.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:111) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:111) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1531) ~[spring-data-redis-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'elastic-cache-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com' after 3 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:467) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:256) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:208) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx] query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)
```

My dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Version of spring boot 3.0.0

I tried to connect with [RedisInsight](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/) and it works

I check some issues that looks very similar, but nothing that help me
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1625
https://github.com/sixthpoint/spring-boot-elasticache-redis-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sixthpoint/spring/boot/elasticcache/redis/config/RedisConfig.java
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-connect-to-aws-elasticache-redis-in-spring-boot-app-9dd2e0908467
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#cluster
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8261

Anyone could you know hoy to solve it?